# How to add logo on the title page (top left corner) for MDPI journals?

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr, logos, mdpi

I tried following code but this code put logo on second page.

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{mdpi} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lhead{\includegraphics[width = 0.3\textwidth]{nanomaterials-logo.png}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me, have you found a solution? I wrote my paper according to the template but didn't see how to add the journal logo.

Answer (score 3):

To add the logo you need to change command `\@maketitle` in the following part (see added code marked with `<====`):

```
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@status}{submit}}{% 
            \includegraphics[width = 0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} % <==================
            \hfill \href{http://www.mdpi.com}{%
            \includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo-mdpi}}\vspace{0.5cm}%
            }
```

With the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[% 
  journal,
  article,
  submit,
  moreauthors,
  pdftex,
  10pt,
  a4paper
]{mdpi}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext} % <========================================

\Title{Title}
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{1,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-000-000X}
\address[1]{%
$^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com}


\makeatletter
%%%% Maketitle part 1: Logo, Arttype, Title, Author
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
    \begin{flushleft}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@arttype}{Supfile}}{%
        \fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont
        \raggedright
        \noindent\textbf{Supplementary Materials: \@Title}%
        \par
        \vspace{12pt}
        \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
        \noindent\boldmath\bfseries{\@Author}
        }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@arttype}{Book}}{}{%
            \vspace*{-1.75cm}
            }
        {%0
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@journal}{preprints}
            \OR \equal{\@arttype}{Book}}{}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@status}{submit}}{% 
          \includegraphics[width = 0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} % <==================
                    \hfill \href{http://www.mdpi.com}{%
                    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo-mdpi}}\vspace{0.5cm}%
                    }{
                    \href{http://www.mdpi.com/journal/\@journal}{
                    \includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{\@journal-logo}}%
                    \hfill
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@journal}{proceedings}}{
                        \href{http://www.mdpi.com/journal/\@journal}{
                        \includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{logo-conference}
                        \hfill}
                        }{}
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@journal}{scipharm}}{%
                        \href{http://www.mdpi.com}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo-mdpi-scipharm}}%
                        }{%
                        \href{http://www.mdpi.com}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo-mdpi}}%
                        }%
                    }%
            }%
        \par
        }%0
        {%1
            \vspace{14pt}
            \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@arttype}{Book}}{}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\@arttype}{Reprint}}{%
                \textit{\ifthenelse{\equal{\@originalarttype}{\@empty}}{Article}{\@originalarttype}}%
                }{%
                \textit{\@arttype}%
                }%
            }%  
        \par%
            }%1
            {%2
        \vspace{-1pt}
        \fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont
        \boldmath\bfseries{\@Title}
        \par
        \vspace{15pt}
        }%2
        {%3
            \boldmath\bfseries{\@Author}
            \par
            \vspace{-4pt}
            }%3
        }
    \end{flushleft}%
    }
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\Blindtext % <=================================

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting title page]

Do you submit an article to that journal? Then I guess that they do not want you to change the layout.  Please ask before submitting if you are allowed to change the layout!

Comment: thanks. Its working. am gonna add journal logo i.e., "nanomaterials" cox i saw this in their journals available at their sites. it is not allowed?

Comment: Well, I do not know what the journal wants, sorry. Better ask them. But usually if you submit a paper use the prepared template without changes. The journal adds that logo in their finishing process ...

Answer (score 0):

Used `\flushleft` in line number 1151 of mdpi.cls as `\flushleft{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo-mdpi}}}\vspace{0.5cm}%`

[image]

Comment: Thnaks alot but i don't wanna flush that logo to left. want to insert another at left side.

Answer (score 0):

The class option "submit" will be changed to "accept" by the Editorial Office when the paper is accepted. This will only make changes to the frontpage (e.g., the logo of the journal will get visible), the headings, and the copyright information. Also, line numbering will be removed. Journal info and pagination for accepted papers will also be assigned by the Editorial Office.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!